# iFrame in JavaFX application not loading certain pages when running on Linux

Tags: java, linux, iframe, webview, javafx

From within my Java FX app, I'm supposed to load a simple HTML page that includes an iframe which displays external websites. I know I can use `webEngine.load()` to load the websites but as a requirement I had to implement it this way (I'm trying to incorporate the Duo Security Web SDK into our Java app).

On Windows, everything works fine. However certain websites are not loading on Linux (Debian, Fedora). I can display sites like gmail (https), espn.com, or en.wikipedia.org. However google and yahoo won't load. I don't think it's a https or flash issue. Please see the code below.

Java:

```
webEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
    new javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener<State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue ov, State oldState, State newState) {
            if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
                webEngine.executeScript(
                      "window.duoHost = '"+duoHost+"';"
                    + "window.duoSigRequest = '"+duoSigRequest+"';"
                    + "loadDuoOptions();");
                JSObject jsobj = (JSObject) webEngine.executeScript("window");
                jsobj.setMember("java", new Bridge());
                System.out.println("Set up done");
            }
        }
    });
```

HTML:

```
<head>
<title>Designer Login with Duo </title>
<script src="Duo-Web-v1.bundled.js"></script>
<script>
    function loadDuoOptions(){
        Duo.init({
            'host' :  window.duoHost,
            'sig_request' : window.duoSigRequest 
        });
        Duo.ready();
    }
    window.processDuoResponse = function(data){
        duoResponse = data;
        loginHandler.verifyDuoResponse(duoResponse);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="duo_iframe" width="500" height="500" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

THis fixes HTTPS:

```
private void installCertificateVerificationBypassTools() {
    this.installCustomTrustManager();
    this.installCustomHostNameverifier();

}

private void installCustomTrustManager() {
    System.out.println("Installing custom trust manager");
    try {
        TrustManager[] nonDiscriminantTrustManager = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // ignore client trust check
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                // ignore server trust check
            }
        }};
        final SSLContext ret = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        ret.init(null, nonDiscriminantTrustManager, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(ret.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {

    }
}

private void installCustomHostNameverifier() {
    System.out.println("Installing custom hostname verifier");
    HostnameVerifier hv = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String string, SSLSession ssls) {
            System.out.println("Verifying connection...");
            showSSLSessionDetails(ssls);
            if (ssls.getProtocol().contains("https")) {
                System.out.println("https session allowed.");
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(hv);
}
```

use **installCertificateVerificationBypassTools()** in the **public void start(Stage mainStage)** method, in the **myClass extends Application** class.

Be advised that this accepts all incoming certificates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually figured out the problem. Another part of the app is actually wiping out the truststore path which causes the SSL communication to fail.